# SQL Statement Issue

Tags: mysql, sql

The following SQL code comes back with everything selected being NULL and the event_size being 0. My tables are set up correctly for the following criteria. What am I doing wrong here? Thank you for your help

```
SELECT table_one.event_id AS event_id, table_one.event_name AS event_name, table_one.event_address AS event_address, COUNT( table_two.user_id ) AS event_size
FROM table_one
JOIN table_two
ON table_one.event_id = table_two.event_id 
WHERE (
       table_one.event_start_date =  '5/10/2012'
    OR table_one.event_mid_date =  '5/10/2012'
    OR table_one.event_end_date =  '5/10/2012'
)
ORDER BY event_size DESC
```

Comment: Not related, but you could do your WHERE like this:  `WHERE '5/10/2012' IN (table_one.event_start_date, table_one.event_mid_date, table_one.event_end_date`

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish. Why are you joining to table two at all? Why are you counting ids when you could use `count(0)`? Why the order by?

Comment: After seeing your comment on dates being strings, I'm frankly puzzled and by more than whatever prompted you to do that. Try ToDate(table_one.event_start_date) = ToDate('5/10/2012')

Comment: I see COUNT( table_two.event_id ) AS event_size in your SELECT statement but I don't see GROUP BY.

Comment: @Eric. Apparently mysql lets you do that which is why it's prime suspect.

Comment: Eric. It should say COUNT(table_two.user_id).
Marc. Im using mysql version 5 something.
Tim. Im trying to get the number of user_ids in table_two that are in the same row as the event_id that matches up with the event_id in table_one.

Comment: Did you just downvote everyone?

Comment: No, and to prove that, I dont have a high enough rep to down vote yet.

Comment: Well only two things could *possibly* to wrong here. Either your join is failing or your where clause is failing. You're pretty adamant that your where clause is right so have you checked your event ids?

Comment: @Tim, My event ids match, and you're right about the where clauses. I might as well have not even put them in my question. But I narrowed down the problem a bit...

SELECT table_one.event_id, table_two id.user_id FROM table_one JOIN table_two ON table_one.event_id = table_two.event_id.... This gives me a bunch of columns like I want but when I add the count function in there it only gives me one column. Does this mean I need to use GROUP BY?

Comment: Fixed it. Not having GROUP BY was the problem.

Comment: @Rick, my aplogies for the implication that you were the sort of "person" who would do something like that.  When I was first introduced to the idea that you could miss out group by in MySQl, my first thought was that's iffy. Seems you delivered the proof. Congratulations I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a group by clause:

```
group by table_one.event_id, table_one.event_name, table_one.event_address
```

This should do what you want.